# Android: RatingBar's value, which is in a ListView, isn't correctly saved in the database

Tags: android, listview

I've got a ListView in which each row consists in a CheckBox, a TextView and a RatingBar. I also have got a database where I store the text, which is unique, the rating as a float and other information which is not relevant here.

Every time I start my application, it gathers the information from the database and shows it on the ListView just fine. Besides the RatingBar. When the user changes the rating of a RatingBar, I'd like to save the new value in the database so that I can use it later together with the rest of information which I store in the database. But the problem is that this value isn't correctly saved, I don't know why, so the value isn't correctly shown or even it's shown in wrong rows.

I tried some codes which I found in this website but I couldn't make it work properly.

This is my custom ArrayAdapter's getView:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        FilaLlistaHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((SeriesDBActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new FilaLlistaHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.rating = (RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);            
            row.setTag(holder);
            if (holder.rating != null) {
                holder.rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                            float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                            if (fromUser) {

                                data[position].stars = rating;
                                FilaLlista filaLlista = data[position];
                                bd.openToWrite();
                                bd.saveRating(filaLlista.titol, rating);
                                bd.close();
                            }
                    }                   
                });
                holder.rating.setRating(data[position].stars);
            }
        }

        else
            holder = (FilaLlistaHolder)row.getTag();

        FilaLlista filaLlista = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(filaLlista.titol);
        holder.rating.setRating(filaLlista.stars);
        return row;
    }
```

As you can see, I've got a setOnRatingBarChangeListener which calls the database to update the row that has changed its rating. And I'd say that update call is correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you know it isn't saving correctly? Maybe it's not retrieving correctly? Have you set a breakpoint(s) in both your retrieve operation and your bd.saveRating(...) operation to check whether or not the correct data is being retrieved/saved?

Comment: Oh my god I feel so embarrassed! The error was indeed on the place where I retrieve the information. I can't believe I've been 2 days fighting against this... Anyway, now it's solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, we've all had those moments.